# Why does Angular InjectionToken wrapped in an object throw an error?

Tags: angular

I'm using InjectionToken for injection of configuration.
This:

configuration.injection-keys.ts

```
export const CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE = {
  offlineproducts: new InjectionToken<OfflineProductsConfig>('core.offlineproducts')
};
```

somemodule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE.offlineproducts,
      useValue: CORE_CONFIGURATION.offlineProducts
    }
  ],
})
```

throws the following error

```
ERROR in Error: Internal error: unknown identifier {"offlineproducts":{"filePath":"D:/angular/src/app/modules/configuration/configuration.injection-keys.ts","name":"CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE","members":[]}}
```

but this does not

configuration.injection-keys.ts

```
export const CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE_OFFLINE_PRODUCTS =
  new InjectionToken<OfflineProductsConfig>('core.offlineproducts');
```

somemodule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE_OFFLINE_PRODUCTS,
      useValue: CORE_CONFIGURATION.offlineProducts
    }
  ],
})
```

I would prefer to have my injection keys structured in an object. Makes it more manageable as it grows.

**Update:**

This error does not happen with `ng build` (or `ng serve`) but it does happen with `ng build --prod`. I double checked all parts of the code that are related to production being enabled and none of them make a difference. Moving CONFIG_INJECTION_KEYS_CORE to the module to have it in the same file makes no difference.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: @AndreiGătej The only part in your link that mentions my case is commented out and mentions putting it in the same file as the provider declaration. I tried and and it does not help. I did update the description because it's only with `ng build --prod`